# Flutter/Riverpod - how to combine providers for fetching data list and holding the data list as state?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I've been playing with the RiverPod 2.0 state management package to understand how to use it for CRUD type operations

What I can't understand is how to use the range of providers to support..

- The asynchronous loading of a data object list prior to displaying it
  in a list view , i.e. a FutureProvider
- Maintaining the data object list
  in a provider to support CRUD use cases, i.e. a StateNotifierProvider.

In my Flutter list view I am reading the data from the StateNotifierProvider, not the FutureProvider.

It seems like you need two distinct providers for this one situation.  Is that correct?

Currently, I am using a FutureProvider to load the data list, and inside this FutureProvider pushing the data into the StateNotifierProvider. Is that the correct approach?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/74509912/14891973 should help.

Answer (score 2):

The new way is to use `AsyncNotifier` to asynchronously read data from a database or server. You can read a good article on the subject in more detail:

[How to use Notifier and AsyncNotifier](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-riverpod-async-notifier/)

The old way, on the other hand, was to use `StateNotifier` with `Async` state.
Something like that:

```dart
final dataProvider = StateNotifierProvider<DATANotifier, AsyncValue<YOURDATA>>((ref) {
  return DATANotifier();
});

class DATANotifier extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<YOURDATA>> {
  DATANotifier() : super(const AsyncValue.loading()) {
    _init();
  }

  Future<void> _init() async {
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() => LocalStorage().getData());
  }

  // Post your CRUD methods for working with data here
}
```

The `FutureProvider` is an asynchronous version of the `StateProvider` in the sense that it does not serve as a place to store and handle large logic.